# Advantages of using NativeActivity over JNICALL callbacks?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, glsurfaceview, native-activity

For the development of a cross platform OpenGL game engine,

1. Is there a performance advantage from using:

   - NativeActivity or android_native_app_glue

     **over:**
   - Defining an Activity, creating a GLSurfaceView, and setting the renderer to call native methods; implementing the JNI calls yourself?
2. If using NativeActivity, are there any disadvantages: e.g. can you still use Google Play Game Services?

Comment: Keep in mind that even a "native activity" is still heavily jni based - it just uses stock java code rather than custom code written by you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed, though I wasn't 100% sure. So realistically, I assume it's still doing a JNI call per frame, which is presumably the significant part of the overhead anyway?

Comment: The JNI call overhead when calling into native code is measured in nanoseconds on modern devices.  It's only significant if you're making a lot of them.  Calling back into the VM from Java is much slower, but we're still talking about a few microseconds.  I would, however, recommend avoiding GLSurfaceView and just using plain SurfaceView, as that will give you full control over the EGL context and threading.  And if you want to do a game engine, you should first read through all of https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html .

Comment: Ah, fair enough, and thanks for the link. When you say "Calling back into the VM from Java," do you mean "Calling back into the VM from native/c?"